# Wordpress | Apply function/filter to specific template (featured image function filter)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following code in my tweaks plugin.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sqhse_news_featimgmove', 20 );

function sqhse_news_featimgmove( $content ) {
    $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'post-single', array( 'class' => "img-fluid img-rounded w-100")) . "<div class='clearfix' style='margin-bottom:10px;'></div>", $content, 1 );
    return $content;
}
```

**What it does:**
It adds the featured image after the first paragraph which is great and exactly what I need.

**The problem:** The code applies itself to single.php (great that's where I need it) but it also applies itself to single-training_courses.php (a template for a custom post type).

**The help required:** Apply the code to single.php and not any sub single templates such as single-training_courses.php

Is this achievable? and if so how may I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_post_type()` WordPress function and wrap your code inside an if statement as follow:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sqhse_news_featimgmove', 20 );

function sqhse_news_featimgmove( $content ) {
    if( get_post_type() == 'post' ) {
        $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'post-single', array( 'class' => "img-fluid img-rounded w-100")) . "<div class='clearfix' style='margin-bottom:10px;'></div>", $content, 1 );
        return $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback.  I tried the proposed solution and it caused a catostrophic failure of the website.

Comment: The above code doesn't involve any change to the content of website, so I highly doubt what you meant by "catastrophic"

Comment: Hi @Varun take a look at the answer from nathan this is much closer to what is requried.  It has the add filter and functions included yours is missing all this information. It is an incomplete answer.

Comment: Okay, I am really sorry for just focusing on the problem area. I will update the answer for you.

Comment: @SapphireBSL I have updated the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for the update the result is the same it kills the website and returns a white screen.

Comment: I have added a return statement. But in any case I don't expect a complete white screen of death. Can you please turn your debug mode on and tell us the error it's generating?

Comment: Partial fix it now shows the single.php correctly but single-training_courses.php returns not post data?

Comment: Broken page: https://www.sapphireqhse.co.uk/training_courses/pasma-standard-users-course/

Comment: Working page: https://www.sapphireqhse.co.uk/industry-news/north-wales-iosh-branch-hears-about-benefits-of-healthy-workforces/

Comment: It works!  Thank you so much for your time @Varun :) Brilliant

Answer (score 0):

The filter you're using, `the_content`, as you've discovered will apply to all content areas. You need to add a conditional to check the post type you're on and adjust accordingly. My suggestion would be to use `is_singular()`.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'sqhse_news_featimgmove', 20 );

function sqhse_news_featimgmove( $content ) {
    if ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) { 
        $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'post-single', array( 'class' => "img-fluid img-rounded w-100")) . "<div class='clearfix' style='margin-bottom:10px;'></div>", $content, 1 );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

When dealing with filters make sure you always return a value. If you have a conditional for example keep the return statement outside of it.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular

Comment: Hi @nathan the code is flagging and error with the { after the if statement?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. There should be two brackets on that line. I've amended my answer.